# Process scheduler runtime parameter

Tags: peoplesoft

Can anyone recommend a fairly clean method for determining the process scheduler an app-engine is running on at run-time (NT or UNIX).  I need to set a file path that is obviously dependent upon the server the process is being executed on.  I understand the GetEnv command can be used, but I don't want to set an environment variable for this particular instance (it does not reside under the PS_FILES) path.  I've searched peoplebooks for any kind of built in function or system variable, but was not successful (obviously).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I may have asked this question a little too early.  I apologize.

It looks like I'll just be able to query the process request table to pull back the server name:

SQLExec("SELECT SERVERNAMERUN FROM PSPRCSRQST WHERE PRCSINSTANCE = :1", &thisProcess, &server);

Evaluate &server

When.......

End-Evaluate;

Answer (score 0):

Exactly :-)

There are a host of Process Request records that can give you the information you need. Glad that you found it.

John

Comment: Thanks for your comment, John.

I found this to be the best table to go after as it always appears to be stamped with the correct server at run-time, where as the users run control and/or the process definition may be blank.  But, like you said there are probably a host of other tables where you could gather this information.